# Tonejs Sequence playing notes multiple times in callback

Tags: scheduling, web-audio-api

I was trying to arpeggiate notes using [Tone.js](https://tonejs.github.io/). I tried using `Tone.Sequence` for this. However, when I call/play the function to play the sequence, the notes are played multiple times.

### First Call:

```
note, seqTime C4 3.846027178065821
note, seqTime E4 3.9464048979942876
note, seqTime G4 4.105932631765658
```

### Second Call

```
note, seqTime C4 6.195315101800973
note, seqTime C4 6.196835114504218
note, seqTime E4 6.311545028802484
note, seqTime E4 6.3175260184741795
note, seqTime G4 6.448273617945778
note, seqTime G4 6.450643820818717
```

Here's the link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bring2dip/qrLsx0nh/16)

Comment: What do you mean by "played multiple times" ?

Comment: @TGrif read the issue: https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/issues/580